# Must I redo the floor as part of a carport conversion?

Tags: carport, remodel, conversion

I live in northern Alabama and was looking to convert my carport into a living room with a fireplace centered on the peak of the house. The front of the house faces the south.

[image: Carport]

Do I need to re-do the concrete?
I worry that the footing for a carport pour is not sufficient for a living space.
The concrete is good condition aside from it needing a good cleaning.
Can I get away with installing flooring with a vapor barrier and insulation?

I am aware of the energy loss and hope to remedy it, however, as I am doing this conversion I want to make sure I am covering all of my bases.

Comment: The type of flooring will matter.  Hard/ridged flooring likes very flat(not level) surface.  More than a few 16ths inch can be needed to be fixed.  Soft flooring like carpets don't care as much if there are some dips/ridges in the floor.  Vapour barrier probably needed, since a carport probably does not have it under.

Comment: Typo: "rigid" I presume.

Comment: You could have simply edited your original question instead of deleting it and retyping it completely. As a matter of face, if you are asked for more info on this question, please just [edit] it to include that info. In particular, please [edit] to clarify what you mean by "do I need to `do` the concrete?" What does `do` mean?

Comment: If you'll take the [tour] and read through [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) that will help you learn how we do things here.